# What type of join do I need to use in the below sql query to retrieve the correct results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return the appropriate information about a user from three different tables in my database using SQL joins and a group concat function. Which joins are appropriate for what I am trying to achieve?

I have three tables I want to use in the table:
users
user_events 
Events

Current SQL code:

```
SELECT users.username, users.user_firstname, users.user_lastname,
       users.user_role, user_events.Event_ID
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_events ON users.id = user_events.id
```

This returns all users, there details and the ID of the event they have signed up to, but this event id is duplicated if they've signed up to one or more.

If I update my query to the below how would I join on the Events table to get the event name?

```
SELECT users.username, users.user_firstname, users.user_lastname,
       users.user_role,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Events.Event_Name) AS Event_Names
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_events ON users.id = user_events.id
```

My output from the first query is as follows:

```
| username    | user_firstname | user_lastname | user_role | event_id.           
| M@gmail.com | jo             | mccann        | employee  | 8                            
| M@gmail.com | jo             | mccann        | employee  | 15
```

Expected output:

```
| username    | user_firstname | user_lastname | user_role | Event_Name                              
| M@gmail.com | jo             | mccann        | employee  | baking,run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add one more `outer join` & do aggregation :

```
SELECT users.username, users.user_firstname, users.user_lastname,
       users.user_role,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Events.Event_Name) AS Event_Names,
       COUNT(Events.Event_Name) AS Event_count
FROM users LEFT JOIN 
     user_events 
     ON users.id = user_events.id LEFT JOIN
     Events 
     ON Events.id = user_events.event_id
GROUP BY users.username, users.user_firstname, users.user_lastname, users.user_role;
```

Use `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()` in case of any duplicate events.

Comment: is it possible to add in a new column which will then display the count of the group_concat Event_Name column? For instance in the Event_Name column a user that has signed up to two events will have baking, running in that column. Can I have an additional column that then has a count of this, in the above case 2 in that row but in na new column??

Comment: @L.Claire. . .  For that, you have to use `COUNT()` function. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far all has worked well. I wanted to expand that current query to include another column that includes previously attended events so WHERE Start_Date < CURDATE(), however not sure where I can add this. I don't want the column Event_Names to include events the user has already been to I just want this to be current events they have signed up to and then add another column as previous events using the start_data and current date. Any idea how I would add this?

Comment: @L.Claire. . .  This question was asked on `Feb-13` & today is `Feb-21`. So, i would suggest you to ask other question & make this as reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.username, users.user_firstname, users.user_lastname,
       users.user_role,
       GROUP_CONCAT(ev.Event_Name) AS Event_Names
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_events ON users.id = user_events.id
JOIN events ev ON ev.event_id = user_events.event_id
```